# put an icon in the task bar through script on domain computers

Tags: taskbar

Question: How can I create a python/batch file that will put an icon in the task bar for all users logins?

---

Info:

We are trying to retrofit a program on to some computers in our computer science lab. We need to put the icon into the task bar, but doing it when I'm logged in only changes my login. Is there a way I can do this, specifically via a script as I need to do it on a couple dozen computers, so that is default to all logins new and existing?

Comment: It would help to know the OS.

Comment: windows 7 enterprise.